# Xcode-apple developer account errors

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

I wanna publish a test flight on i phone that was published a few times before. when I wanna achieve the app's codes on Xcode I get that errors.

Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Select a device run destination to have Xcode register it.

No profiles for 'com.OttoTilesDesign.OttoTilesDesignVisualizer--explicit--' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.OttoTilesDesign.OttoTilesDesignVisualizer--explicit--'.

Comment: Welcome! This really seems like a support issue, not a programming issue. If it *is* a programming issue, you'll need to edit your question to provide specifics.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish you need an "App Store" provisioning profile connected to the "identifier" in your app.
Use this profile in unity and xcode.
Try to create a new one. I had a similar issue and a reimport solved it.

Be sure that you select "any ios device" in the topline of xcode.

you only need a registered device when you want to deploy for internal/local testing.
if you want to do that, you need to register your devices with the uuid under: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list

Comment: thank, i handled it. i couldn't upload the certificate on my device.